# Confirming a Matching Ending Boolean Issue (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, boolean

I'm attempting to create a function that returns if the ending of a string is the same as a given variable without using .endsWith().

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Chaining .join("") and comparing the two values as strings works, but not as arrays.

```
const confirmEnding = (str, target) => {
// split string into array, splice end of array based on target length
console.log(str.split("").splice(str.length - target.length, target.length));
// split target into array
console.log(target.split(""));
// compare two arrays
return str.split("").splice(str.length - target.length, target.length) === target.split("");

console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "on"));
```

OUTPUT

```
[ 'o', 'n' ]
[ 'o', 'n' ]
false
```

Clearly, the arrays are exactly the same. Why does the boolean return false?

Comment: you can not compare two arrays with the same content, but with different object references. you need to compare the item.

Comment: You should read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript and its answers

Comment: Got it, I didn't know arrays couldn't be compared like primitive data types.

Comment: A little help : `a = [1,2,3]; b = [1,2,3]; console.log(a === a); /* true */ console.log(a === b); /* false */` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare two arrays with the same content, but with different object references. You need to compare the item by using a counter for the characters who are equal end iterate from the end of the string.

```js
const confirmEnding = (str, target) => {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < target.length && str[str.length - 1 - i] === target[target.length - 1 - i]) {
      i++;
  }
  return i === target.length;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "on"));
console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "off"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your logic to make it simple. Just get the `lastIndexOf` the `target` string from the `str` so that you can take substring of the last word and compare it with the `target`:

```js
const confirmEnding = (str, target) => {
  var indexOfTarget = str.lastIndexOf(target);
  var lastStr = str.substr(indexOfTarget, str.length - 1);
  if(lastStr === target){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
//match
console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "on"));
//match
console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "tion"));
//no match
console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "ons"));
```

Comment: You don't answer the question : "Why does the boolean return false?".

Comment: @leaf I understood your comment but I preferred to suggest a better answer despite of giving the reason for the answer which is not more appropriate to achieve what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Then [your logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345837/confirming-a-matching-ending-boolean-issue-javascript/49345879?noredirect=1#comment85691538_49345871) is not coherent :-P